# Ajax call works on live server, but not in localhost

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using Codeigniter and send ajax requests. On live server it is working, but on my localhost it shows this error:

> Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in **Unknown** on line **0**

Form data:

```
json:data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: site_url+'design/save_image',
    type: 'POST',
    /*dataType: "json",*/
    data: {
        json: $('#json').text(), 
        file: generate_file_name, 
        product: productss, 
        jsn: jsn
    },
    async: false,
    success: function(res)
    {
        // console.log(res); return false;
        if(res == 'done') 
        {
            console.log('done');
            $('.loading').hide();
            // $('#json').html('<a href="shorts.jpg">Open new file</a>');
            // event.preventDefault();

            $('#tjs').remove();
            $('.tjs_canvas').prepend('<canvas id="tjs" style="width: 100%; height:500px"></canvas>');
            $('#loading').show();
            // init('shorts2.mtl', 'shorts2.obj');
            // animate();
            location.reload();
        }
        else {console.log('error: '+res);}
    },
    error: function(res){
        console.log(res); return false;
        console.log('error: '+res);
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
        {
            sessionStorage.setItem('base', $('#color_svg_1').val());
            sessionStorage.setItem('middle', $('#color_svg_2').val());
            sessionStorage.setItem('top', $('#color_svg_3').val());
        }
        else alert('Local Storage Not Found. Please use chrome or firefox for best experience.');
        $('.loading').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First Open xamppserver
2. Open config => Open Appache(httpd.conf) file
3. In Directory tag, Add this line "php_value max_input_vars 1000000", After "AllowOverride none"
4. After this Save file & restart xampp Server

Answer (score 2):

You should modify your php.ini file in the xammp

max_input_vars = 6000

and restart the xammp server (or wamp what you are using)